# Where clause in an inner join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below query

```
SELECT  b.CreateDate, *
FROM         ConsolidatedData_DealSheet AS a INNER JOIN
                      Deals AS b ON a.DealNo = b.DealNo
```

Result Set

```
2007-11-13 15:40:15.627 07110001    Atlantic
2007-11-13 16:27:13.783 07110002    Midwest
2007-11-13 17:18:47.783 07110003    Midwest
2007-11-16 14:06:27.917 07110004    Atlantic
2007-11-20 12:49:17.343 07110005    Midwest
2007-11-21 10:57:23.903 07110006    Midwest
```

If I change the query and add a date filter shown below

```
SELECT  b.CreateDate, *
FROM         ConsolidatedData_DealSheet AS a INNER JOIN
                      Deals AS b ON a.DealNo = b.DealNo
WHERE     
  b.CreateDate  BETWEEN  
  CONVERT(datetime, '11/16/2007') AND  DATEADD(day,1,CONVERT(datetime,  '11/21/2008'))
```

This is basically just joining ConsolidatedData_DealSheet and Deals and then filtering on the Deals.CreateDate but I don't get any result back.

If I just do

```
select * from Deals where Createdate between   CONVERT(datetime, '11/16/2007') AND  DATEADD(day,1,CONVERT(datetime,  '11/23/2008'))
```

I get all the data.

Can someone have a look and let me know what is wrong with my filter after the Inner join. I am not getting any data at all.

Script not getting any data with where clause

```
 SELECT  b.CreateDate, *
    FROM         ConsolidatedData_DealSheet AS a INNER JOIN
                          Deals AS b ON a.DealNo = b.DealNo
    WHERE     
      b.CreateDate  BETWEEN  
      CONVERT(datetime, '11/16/2007') AND  DATEADD(day,1,CONVERT(datetime,  '11/21/2008'))
```

Thanks

Comment: I know you've posted the results you're after, but can you post some sample data too?

Comment: The evil BETWEEN strikes again ;) Read this please: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Do you get results if you use `WHERE b.CreateDate >= '2007-11-16' AND b.CreateDate < '2008-11-22'` ?

Comment: Although the issue is likely not (only) the `BETWEEN`. Read this, too: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: Also: is `ConvertDate` a datetime column or a string type?

Comment: Are you sure you run all the queries against the same sever and database?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "unclear what you're asking" since you haven't provided the T-SQL table definiitions.  Without those details, it's impossible to determine for certain what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any other logical explanations:

1. You are running the queries against different servers or databases.
2. The datatype of the column is `sql_variant`. This has the result - for the comparison to be performed - that the lower precedence datatype (`CONVERT(datetime, '11/16/2007')` which is `datetime`) is converted to the highest precedence datatype (`b.CreateDate` which is `sql_variant`). The same happens for the 2nd comparison of the `BETWEEN` condition. As a result the comparisons are not done on datetimes but on the internal format that the values get when converted to sql_variant type.

   And that format does not off course preserve date order. It couldn't because it can store values of any type and can't be possibly preserving `date` and `int` and `float` and `varchar` and ... and `datetime` order at the same time.

Test in **[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=773246eca044da990694bd2adfd3422d)**